# Phone immediately disconnects from computer via. Bluetooth when making an attempt to connect

Tags: bluetooth

I am attempting to use an app called Unified Remote to use my phone as a virtual remote for my desktop.

In order for this app to work, my phone needs to be able to maintain a Bluetooth connection with my computer, however, when I try to connect to my computer from my phone, it says connected for about 3 seconds, and then disconnects.

Are there are common reasons for this? Common fixes?

I'm using an HP Envy 360 running Windows 11, and a Pixel 6.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post the desktop PC's OS and version and the same for the phone you're trying to use.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Apologies. I've added these.